# 404 errors when sites-enabled/localhost but not when overriding the default /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: docker, nginx

I've got a docker container that's acting as a reverse proxy for local kubernetes services - I know, I should be using real ingress controllers, but at the moment I'm working with others who are using this configuration and I'm trying to troubleshoot it.

When I have no /etc/nginx/sites-enabled files, and /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is configured like this:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    server_tokens off;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format artformat '$remote_addr,$remote_user,$time_local,"$request",$status,$body_bytes_sent,"$http_referer","$http_user_agent",$request_time';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log artformat;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types application/javascript text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name localhost;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        charset utf-8;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        # Resolve app first.
        location /app/ {
            resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
            set $skill_matrix_app skill-matrix-app.default.svc.cluster.local;
            set $skill_matrix_app_port 8080;
            proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_app:$skill_matrix_app_port;
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0 ,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        }
        # Resolve the angular static files second.
        location ~* /app/.*\.(js|css|gz|png|svg|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot|json|map|txt)$ {
            resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
            set $skill_matrix_app skill-matrix-app.default.svc.cluster.local;
            set $skill_matrix_app_port 8080;
            proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_app:$skill_matrix_app_port;
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0 ,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        }
        # API resolution after the app resolution
        location /api/ {
            resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
            set $skill_matrix_api skill-matrix-api.default.svc.cluster.local;
            set $skill_matrix_api_port 8000;
            proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_api:$skill_matrix_api_port;
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0 ,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        }
        # Admin comes after the app and it's static files.
        location /admin/ {
            resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
            set $skill_matrix_api skill-matrix-api.default.svc.cluster.local;
            set $skill_matrix_api_port 8000;
            proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_api:$skill_matrix_api_port;
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0 ,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        }
        # Add static resolution for django files
        location ~* /static/.*\.(js|css|gz|png|svg|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot|json|map|txt)$ {
            resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
            set $skill_matrix_api skill-matrix-api.default.svc.cluster.local;
            set $skill_matrix_api_port 8000;
            proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_api:$skill_matrix_api_port;
        }
    }
}
```

Things work great - I can get the app:
[image: localhost/app]

When I move the server config into /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/localhost like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    # Resolve app first.
    location /app/ {
        resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
        set $skill_matrix_app skill-matrix-app.default.svc.cluster.local;
        set $skill_matrix_app_port 8080;
        proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_app:$skill_matrix_app_port;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0 ,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    }
    # Resolve the angular static files second.
    location ~* /app/.*\.(js|css|gz|png|svg|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot|json|map|txt)$ {
        resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
        set $skill_matrix_app skill-matrix-app.default.svc.cluster.local;
        set $skill_matrix_app_port 8080;
        proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_app:$skill_matrix_app_port;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0 ,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    }
    # API resolution after the app resolution
    location /api/ {
        resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
        set $skill_matrix_api skill-matrix-api.default.svc.cluster.local;
        set $skill_matrix_api_port 8000;
        proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_api:$skill_matrix_api_port;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0 ,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    }
    # Admin comes after the app and it's static files.
    location /admin/ {
        resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
        set $skill_matrix_api skill-matrix-api.default.svc.cluster.local;
        set $skill_matrix_api_port 8000;
        proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_api:$skill_matrix_api_port;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0 ,no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    }
    # Add static resolution for django files
    location ~* /static/.*\.(js|css|gz|png|svg|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot|json|map|txt)$ {
        resolver 10.96.0.10 valid=30s;
        set $skill_matrix_api skill-matrix-api.default.svc.cluster.local;
        set $skill_matrix_api_port 8000;
        proxy_pass http://$skill_matrix_api:$skill_matrix_api_port;
    }
}
```

and remove that server configuration from the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    server_tokens off;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format artformat '$remote_addr,$remote_user,$time_local,"$request",$status,$body_bytes_sent,"$http_referer","$http_user_agent",$request_time';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log artformat;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types application/javascript text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

I start getting 404 not found and it looks like it's trying to find these files in the html root instead of proxying them:

```
2022/06/28 22:47:46 [error] 32#32: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/app/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2022:22:47:46 +0000] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Why is it trying to find app/index.html instead of proxying to the service?

Comment: Are there any other server blocks gets included? Check it with the `nginx -T` command.

Comment: Diffing the only difference between the functional vs. non-functional is that in the functional set, the server block is within the http block - in the non-functional it's outside the http block - no additional blocks, only in the http block vs. out of the http block.

```
events{}
http {
   server {}
}
```
vs. 
```
events{}
http{}
server{}
```
The diff of the two outputs is identical other than that nesting vs. lack of nesting.

Comment: I solved it - it was the default.conf overriding behavior - found the command in `RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf ` in https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-nginx-plus-docker/ that has me remove the default.conf that was obliterating it and hiding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding a removal line to the dockerfile to remove the default.conf based on https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-nginx-plus-docker/:

```
FROM nginx:1.21

RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
COPY error/ /var/www/html
COPY index.html /var/www/html
COPY favicon.ico /var/www/html
COPY localhost.crt /opt/nginx/ssl_keys/ssl.crt
COPY localhost.key /opt/nginx/ssl_keys/ssl.key
COPY sites-enabled/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
```

Once I did that, the default.conf was no longer overriding and trying to get everything to look at the local host.